# Height of div in a nested div structure in different screen resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with nested DIVs. My question is, how to ensure that one of them (id=first_tab,second_tab) will fill the space of its parent (id=div_korpus), so it looks the same in all screen resolutions and browsers. (I refer to the line that surrounds the left panel).

At the moment I use "em" units to measure their height, which work best of all, but it doesn't feel the whole parent element at higher screen resolutions (there can be a lot of space below it). I tried to use a viewport unit ("vh"), but it gave a similar effect, also moving upwards the whole left panel when clicked on links Ln1, Ln2,Ln3.

What unit of measurement should I use here to make it work?

https://jsfiddle.net/crfpp0jn/

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19%;
  left: 26%;
  right: 8px;
  bottom: 5%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#side {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8em;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 .5em 0
}


/************************* TABS PART **********************/

.korpus>div,
.korpus>input {
  display: none;
}

.korpus label {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  line-height: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

.korpus input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.korpus>input:nth-of-type(1):checked~div:nth-of-type(1),
.korpus>input:nth-of-type(2):checked~div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="green">
                <p align="left">
                  <font face="Calibri, sans-serif">
                    <font style="font-size: 22pt; color: white" size="5"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the Header</b></font>
                  </font>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#191919" colspan="3">
                <div style="text-align:left">
                  <font style="font-size: 22px" face="Calibri, sans-serif">
                    <a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none" href="item1.html"><span style='font-size:16.0pt;color:white;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Item 1</b></span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none" href="item2.html">
                      <span style='font-size:16.0pt;color:white;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'><b>Item 2</b></span></a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none" href="item3.html">
                      <span style='font-size:16.0pt;color:white;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'><b>Item 3</b></span></a>
                  </font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#191919">
                <div style="text-align:left" align="center">
                  <font style="font-size: 17px" face="Calibri, sans-serif"><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none" href="item4.html"><span style='font-size:14.0pt;color:white;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Item 4</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none" href="item5.html"><span style='font-size:14.0pt;color:white;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Item 5</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none" href="item6.html">
                      <span style='font-size:14.0pt;color:white;font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"'>Item 6</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="side">
    <div style="height:3px"></div>
    <!-- BLANK LINE ABOVE TABS -->
    <div id="div_korpus" class="korpus">
      <input type="radio" name="one" checked="checked" id="vkl1" />
      <label for="vkl1">Tab A</label>
      <input type="radio" name="one" id="vkl2" />
      <label for="vkl2">Tab B</label><input type="radio" name="one" id="vkl3" />
      <div id="first_tab" style="height: 23em">
        <!-- FIRST TAB -->

        <p>
          <a href="#ln1">Ln1</a>
          <a href="#ln2">Ln2</a>
          <a href="#ln3">Ln3</a>
          <!-- SCROLL DIV -->
        </p>
        <div id="scrolldiv" style="height: 20em; overflow-y:scroll">
          <p>
            <font style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; color:black" face="TimesNewRoman">
              <span><a>one</a></span><br>
              <span><a>two</a></span><br>
              <span><a>three</a></span><br>
              <span><a name="ln1">1. Link1</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a name="ln2">2. Link2</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a name="ln3">3. Link3</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
          </p>
          </font>
        </div>
        <!-- SCROLL DIV ENDS -->
      </div>
      <!-- FIRST TAB ENDS -->
      <div id="second_tab" style="height: 23em">
        <!-- SECOND TAB -->
        <br>
        <p align="center">
          <font face="Calibri, sans-serif">
            <font size="3" style="font-size: 12pt">Some more stuff here</font>
          </font><br><br>
      </div>
      <!-- SECOND TAB ENDS -->
    </div>
    <!-- KORPUS ENDS -->
  </div>
  <!-- LEFT FRAME ENDS -->
  <div id="main">
    <p id="lex" style="margin-left:2cm; margin-top:1cm">Some general text here
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get with the [flex-box](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) program!

I had to abandon everthing you wrote above and started from scratch but this is the direction I recommend you head.

You should also not apply any inline styles. All styling belongs in you stylesheet.

```css
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, p, th, td, a, em, img, strong, ul, li, form, label, h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html, body, form, #Site {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#Site{
  overflow: auto;
  background:#eee;
}
header{
  background:#008000;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
}
header h1{
  padding:10px;
}
header ul{
 background:#191919;
 list-style:none;
}
header li{
  padding:5px;
}
#Lst1{
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-weight:700;
}
#MainWrap{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:6px 3px;
}
.Flx {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.FlxCol {
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.Flx1 {
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

 /************************* TABS PART **********************/

aside{
  -ms-flex: 200px 0 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 200px 0 1;
  flex: 200px 0 1;
  max-height:100%;
}
.tab{
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
}
#first_tab{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#scrolldiv{
  overflow-y:auto;
  height:100%;
}
.korpus{
  max-height:100%;
 }
.korpus > div, 
.korpus > input { 
  display: none;
}
.korpus label {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  line-height: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}
.korpus input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.korpus > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ div:nth-of-type(1),
.korpus > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="Site" class="Flx FlxCol">
    <header>
      <h1>This is the Header</h1>
      <ul id="Lst1" class="Flx">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="Flx">
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
      </ul>
    </header>

    <div id="MainWrap" class="Flx Flx1">
      <aside class="Flx FlxCol">
        <div id="tabs" class="korpus">
          <input type="radio" name="one" checked="checked" id="vkl1" />
          <label for="vkl1">Tab A</label>
          <input type="radio" name="one" id="vkl2" />
          <label for="vkl2">Tab B</label><input type="radio" name="one" id="vkl3" />

          <div id="first_tab" class="tab Flx Flx1 FlxCol">
            <div>
              <a href="#ln1">Ln1</a>
              <a href="#ln2">Ln2</a>
              <a href="#ln3">Ln3</a>
            </div>
            <div id="scrolldiv" class="Flx1">
              <span><a>one</a></span><br>
              <span><a>two</a></span><br>
              <span><a>three</a></span><br>
              <span><a name="ln1">1. Link1</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a name="ln2">2. Link2</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a name="ln3">3. Link3</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
              <span><a>and more</a></span><br>
            </div>
            <!-- SCROLL DIV ENDS -->
          </div>
          <!-- FIRST TAB ENDS -->
          <div id="second_tab" class="tab">
            <!-- SECOND TAB -->
            Some more stuff here
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- SECOND TAB ENDS -->
      </aside>

      <section id="main" class="Flx1">
        Some general text here
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

**LEARNING FLEX**

The key components are set in the classes `Flx` and `Flx1` in my answer above. `display:flex` tells all it's children to fill the available space. `flex:1` tells the child what ratio of the space to take up.
Here is a great place to test out what flex can do.

[Flexbox playground](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv)

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't know CSS Flex very well. What's the crucial part of this spec that makes an element spread all over the parent, is it these:-webkit-box-orient: vertical;  flex-direction: column;

Comment: Thanks! My task is to fix the height of "div_korpus" between the header and bottom of the page, and provide scrolling inside its daughter element "first_tab". What Flex property can to that?

Comment: Great, now I understand it better. BTW, now I'm trying to incorporate the element with tabs ("korpus") into this code, but its borderline doesn't appear (I changed background of "aside" to white and added a padding of 3px). Is there a conflict with your part of style?

Comment: Well, almost, except that "some more stuff here" should be under 2nd Tab B, please!

Comment: @user1274925 It just needed a minor tweak. Moved the tab div so the css sibling selector works. Have fun :)

Comment: Your help is much appreciated!